# Open new Worksheet with Paste Button

Tags: vba, excel, paste

I am working on a macro for a user to click a button and populate a new worksheet where there will be another macro button solely functioning as a PASTE button would, and the user can paste the screenshot with whatever they have copied.  Currently, the user clicks a button named "add screen shot", and a input box will populate asking the user what they would like to name the screen shot worksheet.  The user writes in a title and a new tab is formed with the name of the worksheet as the user's inputted title.  Here is the code to do so:

```
Sub AddScreenShot()

Dim Title As Variant


Title = Application.InputBox("Enter a Title:  ", "Add Screen Shot", , 400, 290, , , Type:=2)

    If Title = False Then
        Exit Sub

    ElseIf Title = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "A title was not entered.  Please enter a Title"
        Exit Sub

    ElseIf Len(Title) > 15 Then
        MsgBox "No more than 15 characters please"
        Run "AddScreenShot"

    Else

   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).name = Title

    End If


End Sub
```

I already have the subroutine that pastes the clipboard image into the active cell within the open sheet:

```
Sub Paste_Image()

On Error GoTo PasteError

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("E5").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=xxxx

GetOutOfHere:
    Exit Sub

PasteError:
    MsgBox "Please verify that an image has been copied", vbInformation, "Paste Image"
    Resume GetOutOfHere

End Sub
```

The issue is I do not know how to link these two snippets of code together, so that when the user enters the title of the sheet and clicks OK, the new sheet populates with a macro button that will run the paste subroutine above.  Any suggestions on linking the two, and making the paste sub run when the user click OK to create a new worksheet?

Thanks.

Comment: After the `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).name = Title` line you can explicitly call Paste_Image by adding the code `Call Paste_Image`

Comment: Thanks Josh.. I tried that previously, but the issue there is that when the new sheet is created the Paste_Image code literally is populated into cell E5, because I have not created a Form Button that runs that macro.. The issue I guess is populating a Button onto that new worksheet that can run that Paste_Image Sub

Comment: Ah yes, I skipped over the last (and most important) part.  Let me think on this a bit more, I may be able to come up with something for you.  You could try having a mock sheet with a Command Button already on the sheet, and instead of adding a worksheet in the `AddScreenShot()` subroutine, copy the mock worksheet (which will already have the button on it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the button at at runtime.

Using this method, you programmatically add a button when the sheet is created.

```
Dim btn As Button
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim t As Range
Dim sht As Sheet 'Added to ensure we don't add duplicate sheets


Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1))

Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
   With btn
     .OnAction = "Paste_Image" 'Calls the Paste_Image subroutine when clicked
     .Caption = "Paste" 'Change caption as you see fit
     .Name = "btnPaste" 'Change name as you see fit
   End With
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

So your full code should look something like this:

```
Sub AddScreenShot()

    Dim Title As Variant
    Dim btn As Button
    Dim t As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Title = Application.InputBox("Enter a Title:  ", "Add Screen Shot", , 400, 290, , , Type:=2)

        If Title = False Then
            Exit Sub

        ElseIf Title = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "A title was not entered.  Please enter a Title"
            Exit Sub

        ElseIf Len(Title) > 15 Then
            MsgBox "No more than 15 characters please"
            Run "AddScreenShot"

        Else

            On Error Resume Next
            Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Title)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not sht Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "A worksheet named " & Title & " already exists!"
                Run "AddScreenShot"

            Else

                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = Title
                Set t = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2") 'Button will appear in cell A1:B2, change to whatever you want.

                Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height) 'This will make the button the size of the cell, may want to adjust
                With btn
                  .OnAction = "Paste_Image" 'Calls the Paste_Image subroutine when clicked
                  .Caption = "Paste" 'Change caption as you see fit
                  .Name = "btnPaste" 'Change name as you see fit
                End With

                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            End If
        End If


    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Josh. This looks like a neat work-around.. It doesn't like the 

Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1,1))

and errors there.

Comment: Yeah I updated to make it Range("A1:B2") which will place a button the size of the range A1:B2.  Sorry about that!  That's what I get for posting code before I test!

Comment: HAHA I changed it to that before I read this! Great minds think alike! Thanks Josh works awesome.

Comment: Hey Josh quick question to add to this wanted to see if you knew.  If I wanted to add an ElseIf statement to the AddScreenShot Sub that said if the Title entered was already the name of an active sheet, then MsgBox and basically re-run the sub.  
What I have is :
ElseIf Title = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets Then
MsgBox "You already have a worksheet named" & Title "Please select another"
Run "AddScreenShot

But it does not like this code at all.  Anything you can think that would be better?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found a convenient way to test if a sheet exists.  Previously, I would use error-trapping to determine if the sheet exists.  I will update my code to show you.

Comment: I updated my answer.  I used a new variable `sht` and then error trapping to determine whether or not the sheet exists.  Some may criticize this as inappropriate error handling, but the other option is to simply loop through the entire workbook and compare sheet names and test for a match, which seems even worse in my opinion.

Comment: I did test it and it seemed to work as expected, I could probably re-formulate it as an ElseIf if required but it seemed to get the job done for me.